# Canonicalize URL with web.config

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I want to Canonicalize my URLs. and I found this Seo site checker , said my website is not Canonicalized. and it shows using these codes on .htaccess will help. but my websites needs to be changed on web.config on IIS. Can any one tell me what is the equivalent of these codes for web.config?

redirect http://www.example.com to http://example.com,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

and for redirect http://example.com to http://www.example.com,

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the web.config URL rewrite rule of your mentioned .htacess rule:

```
 <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example\.com$" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 1-1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

To convert rules from .htaccess to web.config you can use the import feature of the IIS URL Rewrite Module:

1)go to IIS Manager

2)click your site in the tree

3)double-click URL Rewrite in the Feature View

4)click Import Rules in the Actions panel

5)paste your .htaccess rules into the Rewrite rules textbox and you'd see your converted rules below.

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules) about this feature.

make sure you installed the URL rewrite module in iis. if not then you could download it from the below-mentioned link:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite